# Get the total count of rows and rows limited by number with same query

Tags: mysql, select, count

Suppose in table A i have many rows with column values a,b,c,d.

Out of these, I want 10 rows with column value 'c' while also counting the total number of rows with column value 'c'.

i tried:

```
select count(*),* from A where column like 'c'; (without limit)

select count(*),* from A where column like 'c' limit 10;
```

Is this even possible? or would i have to fire two queries.

Comment: You can use `union` but why not simply run two queries.

Comment: would firing 2 queries be better than one query ???

Comment: Depends on your application. Two queries may induce a race condition risk (the two results could be different if some changes happened in between). But in your question I don't see the interest of getting 10 of `c` rows (with no other constraint or ordering) as well as the total count at the same time.

Comment: The information ill receive will be passed as ajax result and then the images will be displayed. In case of 80 or more images it takes a lot of time so I am trying to selectively load only first 10 and then load the others later.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT n.*, AA.cnt 
FROM nei_product_background_category c
    INNER JOIN nei_backgrounds n ON n.background_id = c.background_id
    INNER JOIN ( 
        SELECT cc.product_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
        FROM nei_product_background_category cc
                    INNER JOIN nei_backgrounds nn ON nn.background_id = cc.background_id
        GROUP BY cc.product_id
    ) AA ON c.product_id = AA.product_id
WHERE
    c.product_id = 578
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: gives me an error. "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT nei_backgrounds.*, AA.cnt INNER JOIN (SELECT  background_id, COUNT(*) AS ' at line 1"

Comment: would uyo mind posting the full query in your question please?

Comment: SELECT nei_backgrounds.*, AA.cnt 
FROM nei_backgrounds
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  background_id, COUNT(*) AS `cnt`
        FROM nei_backgrounds
        WHERE  background_id in (select background_id from nei_product_background_category where product_id = 578)
        GROUP BY background_id
    ) AA ON nei_backgrounds.column = AA.column
WHERE nei_backgrounds.column (select background_id from nei_product_background_category where product_id = 578)
LIMIT 10

Comment: In the results cnt = 1 while i am getting 10 results.Something is incorrect

Comment: 'SELECT background_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
        FROM nei_backgrounds 
        GROUP BY background_id' itself sets cnt as 1

Comment: Yeah, that's because it grouped by background and not by product. I changed it, could you check it?

Comment: I guess its on the right track but since you do not have the table structure ill have to edit it. thank you so much.Something is amiss. ill test and let you know

Comment: I'll be glad to help furthermore if you wish